# Update parent in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I update a parent or remove a parent? In the end, I want to remove "Aufgabe1" and all other child. I also want to update the name of the parent "Aufgabe1" I hope someone understands what I mean. I code in javascript [image]

Comment: Can you show the complete database structure ?

Comment: Setting it's value to "" or deleting it are two options. e.g. aufgabe1Ref.setValue("") will delete it as keys cannot exist without values. There's also a .remove function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your complete database structure is unclear but to delete data from the realtime database is to use the `.remove()` function or just set that specific node to null as shown below.

```
firebase.database().ref("/path/to/Aufgabe1").set(null).then(() => {
  console.log("Data Deleted")
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log("Failed to delete the data", e)
})
```

This will delete the whole Aufgabe1 node. You can't rename the node name itself. To do so, you would have to delete the node name with old name and create a new one with updated name.

Comment: I already thought, that there is no way to rename. But thanks for your answer